# Перезапуск функции после выполнения AJAX запроса

Tags: javascript, ajax, frontend

Пытаюсь разобраться с AJAX, прошу помочь.
Имеется список из нескольких элементов и кнопка для добавления новых элементов в список. С помощью JS каждому элемента списка добавляется его порядковый номер.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    let listNumber = new List();
});

function List() {
    let btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
    let list = document.querySelector('#ul');
    let listItems = list.querySelectorAll('li');

    listCount(listItems);

    btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
        addItem('./item.html', list);
    });

    function listCount(items) {
        for(let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            items[i].innerHTML = i + 1 + " " + items[i].innerHTML;
        }
    }

    function addItem(address, holder) {
        let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('GET', address);
        request.send();
        request.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {
            if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
                let newItem = request.responseText;
                holder.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', newItem);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

```html
<ul id="ul">
  <li>Lorem</li>
  <li>ipsum</li>
  <li>dolor</li>
</ul>
<button id="btn">Add item</button>
```

В item.html лежит одинокий элемент li:

```html
<li>sit</li>
```

Собственно вопрос: каким образом можно перевызвать функцию listNumber чтобы после AJAX запроса она заново перенумеровывала все элементы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function listCount(items) {
    for(let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        var span = items[i].querySelector('.number');
        if (span)
          span.textContent = i + 1 + " ";
        else
          items[i].innerHTML = "<span class='number'>" + (i + 1) + " </span>" + items[i].innerHTML;
    }
}

    ...
    request.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {
        if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
            let newItem = request.responseText;
            holder.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', newItem);
            listCount(holder.querySelectorAll('li'));
        }
    });
```